# Regular expresion two or three digits and consequently allow only one or two letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that, if I write two digits, only allows two letters, but if I write three numbers, only allows one letter

```
123A --> OK
12AB--> OK
AAAA-> KO
1234--> KO
1AAA-> KO
A111-> KO
123AB --> KO
```

Thi is the reg I have right now

```
(\d{2,3})([a-zA-Z]{1,2})?$
```

that I'm trying in https://regex101.com/

but it allows this:
123AB --> KO

Comment: what about `21AB2B` ?  Is that allow ?

Comment: don't try to be "smart" and just write it out `(^ 2 digits 2 letters $) | (^ 3 digits 1 letter $)`

Comment: If you like KISS principle's, I think @gog idea would be best.  eg.  `/(^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}$)|(^\d{3}[A-Z]$)/`..  Reason is that it's easy with this regex to see it's 2 number 2 letters, or 3 numbers 1 letter.  Also if you want it case insensitive, instead of `[a-zA-Z]` just add `/i` to the end -> `/(^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}$)|(^\d{3}[A-Z]$)/i` or if using `new RegExp` add the case insensitive option to the flags.

Comment: Just to mention, another option by use of a lookahead: [`^(?!.{5})\d{2,3}[A-Z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/m6RX46/1) but better to avoid if it can be done without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d{2}(\d[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Laguqu/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(\d[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{2})` - a capturing group that matches either a digit and a letter, or two letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```bash
^(?:[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pTomGV/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:
`^\d{2,3}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$`

[image]

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/l7XjNy/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case insensitive match with `/i` and:

```
^\d{2}(?!\d{2}$)[A-Z\d]{2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `(?!\d{2}$)` Assert not 2 digits to the end of the string
- `[A-Z\d]{2}` Match 2 chars A-Z or a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPcdVn/1)